# How can I specify which differences to merge in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, visual-studio-2013

When I merge two branches in Visual Studio 2013 there is a Merge button for each conflict. When I click the Merge button it combines both files automatically. How can I specify which differences to keep between the files.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzw2k91ueu0i2bl/vs-merge.png

Answer (score 0):

In the 3-way view (source, target, merged panes), you can check the boxes in either pane to include them in the merge, and the 3rd pane (merge result) should be editable for when you need to tweak the results.

When there's significant overlaps like this, you can take one side, and then edit in the remaining changes.